# wordpress mod_rewrite theme redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a plugin "Theme My Login" for WordPress 3.0.1 which causes my user's profile pages to be here:

`domain.com/login-2?action=profile`

instead of here:

`domain.com/profile`

So I am trying to fix it with mod_rewrite like this:

`RewriteRule ^profile /login-2?action=profile`

But it seems to do nothing. I suspect it's some weird thing happening in WordPress but wanted to ask folks here if my rewrite rule looks correct before I dig further. Did I do it right?

Comment: You might try posting on the WordPress-specific site if you haven't already: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, I believe that WordPress uses the value of `REQUEST_URI` when routing the request. Your rule

```
RewriteRule ^profile /login-2?action=profile
```

...should correctly rewrite `/profile` to `/login-2?action-profile`, but WordPress will not observe this change because the value of `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` in PHP is based on the original request send to the server.

It might be possible to work around this by getting WordPress to use `PATH_INFO` instead through modification of the default WordPress permalink block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0
```

It's also possible to use the [`P` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to proxy the rewritten request through, which will update the `REQUEST_URI`. It comes with the overhead of creating a new request, so I'm not sure if I'd recommend it:

```
RewriteRule ^profile /login-2?action=profile [P]
```